# How can I use Drupal8 by using SQL Server with Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, drupal-8

I am trying use docker build drupal-8, but I want SQL Server to be my database

Now, I using docker-compose to setting but it's doesn't work. It's still only
[image: drupal_web]

here is my docker-compose.yml file txt

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    image: drupal:8
    ports:
        - "83:80"
    links:
      - db 
    restart: always
  db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux
    volumes:
      - mssqlTest:/var/opt/mssql/data

volumes:
  mssqlTest:
```

Comment: I can't run that file; it looks like you've attached some sort of image instead of the Docker Compose YAML file.  Can you replace the image with the actual text of the file you're running?  What part of your application produces the first image?

Comment: @DavidMaze 
After docker-compose up, and running " http://localhost:83 "

Comment: The drupal 8 docs make no mention of SQL Server as a data store. I guess 
 it isn't supported on the drupal side. https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/install-requirements.html

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thx! Maybe I should try this way https://www.drupalonwindows.com/es/comment/77. 
It's seems not supported in docker.

Comment: OK so drupal does support SQL Server. This is now well out of my area of expertise. I guess you just need to follow that page to the letter.

Comment: For example that page says you need to add this to your composer.json:         `"post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles",
   "xcopy /S /I /E /Y web\\modules\\contrib\\sqlsrv\\drivers web\\drivers"
        ]`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, by using composer or other way.
Still trying now